# How to get a list of all pages that have "hide physical urls from search" checked

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

I have to check all my pages if "hide physical urls from search" is checked. How can I get a list of all these pages that have this option activated? Can this be done with powershell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go.

**With powershell.**

```
if ( (Get-PSSnapin -Name Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null )
{
    Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Write-Host "[INIT] Loading SharePoint Powershell Snapin" -ForegroundColor Green
}
else{
    Write-Host "[INIT] SharePoint Powershell Snapin already loaded" -ForegroundColor Magenta
}
Write-Host "[INIT]"
Write-Host "Please wait, this won't take long"

$web = Get-SPWeb http://YOURSITE
$list = $web.Lists["Pages"]
$hidePhysicalUrlsFromSearch = $list.Items | where {$_['PublishingIsFurlPage'] -eq 1} # 0=Show; 1=Hide
$hidePhysicalUrlsFromSearch | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "Page title:" $_['Title'] -ForegroundColor Green
    Write-Host "Page URL:  "$_['ows_EncodedAbsUrl'] -ForegroundColor Green
    Write-Host "hide Physical Urls From Search:"$_['PublishingIsFurlPage'] -ForegroundColor Green `n"---"
}
$web.Dispose();
```

**With CAML**

Download CAML Query Builder
http://www.u2u.be/Software

Connect to your site and on list "Pages" execute this query.

```
<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="PublishingIsFurlPage" /><Value Type="Boolean">1</Value></Eq></Where></Query>
```

Comment: I know this question is get property value of "hide physical urls from search" But Can you please let me know how can I set the value for "hide physical urls from search"?